# Defining collision rules in Farseer XNA

Tags: xna, entity-system, collision-resolution, farseer-physics-engine

I'm trying to integrate Farseer into my XNA game.
Since I'm using an EntityComponentSystem approach, I've added the Body inside a component and added it to the players' components.

One thing I'm struggling with is that I don't know how to control "collision rules".

For example,

I want `Players` to **colide with** `other Players/Walls`, but not `move them on contact`, which is what happens when I set `BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic`.

I want players to be able to block other players, but I what happens now is that if a player remains still, if another player runs into them, they move, physically, which is not the kind of behavior I want.

I move them by giving them a `LinearVelocity`, and then when I `Step` the `World`, I set the players' position to their `Body`'s position. I tried changing `BodyType = BodyType.Static`, but that removed the collision between the players.

I know that if it was Unity, I'd give the object a `BoxCollision2D` and a `RigidBody2D` and it'd behave like I want. I guess that what I'm missing is the `RigidBody` part of the collision, but how can I implement it in `Farseer`?